# Slideshow needs to pause after using navigation buttons

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I want my slideshow navigation buttons to move between images, pause on that image, and then continue running the slideshow. Currently the image changes when the user clicks. Depending on when this event happens, the slideshow skips images or shows two quickly. I am not sure how to create the pause I want before the slideshow continues. My code currently looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    var step = 0;
    function slideIt(){
        if(!document.images) return; 
            document.getElementById('slide').src = slideshow[step].src;
                if (step < 3){
                    step++;
                }
                else{
                    step = 0;
                }
            setTimeout('slideIt()', 3500);
    }
    function previousImg(){
        if(!document.getElementById) return;
            document.getElementById('slide').src = slideshow[step].src;
                if (step > 0){
                    step--;
                }
                else{
                    step = 3;
                }
    }
    function nextImg(){
        if(!document.getElementById) return;
            document.getElementById('slide').src = slideshow[step].src;
                if (step < 3){
                    step++;
                }
                else{
                    step = 0;
                }
    }
    slideIt();
</script>
```

Again, I do not want the slideshow to stop completely, just pause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to reset the timeout. When setting the timeout, hold a reference to it:

```
var tout; //declare a variable that will hold reference to your timeout***
var step = 0;
function slideIt(){
    if(!document.images) return; 
    document.getElementById('slide').src = slideshow[step].src;
        if (step < 3) {
            step++;
        }
        else {
            step = 0;
        }
    tout = setTimeout(slideIt, 3500); //***
}
```

Then, when user clicks, reset the timeout, i.e. make it start all over again:

```
clearTimeout(tout);
tout = setTimeout(slideIt, 3500);
```

Or better, wrap it into a separate function:

```
function restartTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(tout);
    tout = setTimeout(slideIt, 3500);
}
```

And just call that function from within `slideIt()`.

PS. Make sure, that the number of slides is not hardcoded in your final code (I mean the `3` in your snippet) and remember about **`DRY` rule (don't repeat yourself)**: your functions seem to be very similar to each other.

Comment: It works pretty well for the forward button, but I am running into two problems: it gets jumpy toward the end of the timeout period when the button is clicked and it doesn't seem to work for the back button.

Comment: Could you post the code that you invoke when the buttons are clicked (i.e. when do you actually invoke those `previousImg()` and `nextImg` functions)?
And what do you mean by *it gets jumpy* :)?

Comment: The html code looks like this: <button href="#" id="back" onclick="previousImg();"><<</button>. It is basically the same for the other button. By jumpy I mean that it will go to the next image and immediately change to the image that follows that when the button is clicked towards the end of the timeout period.

Comment: 1. The problem with the back button is that when running `previousImg` function you actually use the value of `step`, that was set in a previous invocation of e.g. `nextImg`. To prevent that you should  increment/decrement the `step` before changing the slide rather than doing it after.
2. Make sure that you clear timeout in functions `nextImg` and `previousImg` too and that you do it with `tout = setTimeout(slideIt, 3500);` and not with string `tout = setTimeout('slideIt()', 3500);`